# invalid campaign missing pageid 0

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to retrieve a campaign but I'm getting "**invalid campaign** 505a03ede4b022fe1d3c3c6e **missing pageid 0**". This API call is working before. The campaign also exists. The API documentation for retrieving campaign details has not changed as well https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/campaigns/campaigns. May I know the correct parameter to supply?

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Visit this URL (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=simulate/campaigns/4e0deba2922e6f94b1410b79) to see an example of a valid campaign response. Make sure that the campaign exists on foursquare.com. You should not need any parameters other than a valid campaign ID. Ensure that you are using the ID of the campaign, and not the venue.